# XAMPP, Ajax, jQuery - Keeps reading commented lines OR code is not updated in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, xampp, localhost

EDIT2: I edit this and open it again, the problem continues. Now I've added code and doesn't read it at all, I hit F12 and JS file is not updated :/ I don't know what to do...

EDIT: I closed the projects (in the browser tabs) and re-opened them, and somehow the commented lines were not read anymore. It just fixed itself.

I'm working on the login part of a web application project, and I'm trying out different parts of code.. because it's not working :/

But... I can't do much right now, I've commented the lines that were causing trouble, but when loaded, it keeps giving an error in console reading those lines! :/ Any ideas on what could I do to fix this?

(Below --> Previous problem)
Here is the code from the ajax code that's giving trouble:

```
function login(){

if(validacionLogin()){
        /*$.ajax({
                url: "",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"usuarioInfo": usuarioInfo, 
                       "passwordInfo": passwordInfo, 
                       },
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function() {    
                    console.log("Procesando...");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if( data == "OK"){
                        //alert("Existe usuario");
                        //location.href = "";
                        return;
                    }

                    if( data == "ERROR"){
                        //alert("No existe usuario");
                        // alert("Hubo un error, por favor intente nuevamente");
                        return;
                    }

                    alert("Mensaje del servidor: " + data);

                }

        });*/

        alert("WIIII");
        console.log("Usuario: "+usuarioInfo);
        console.log("Password: "+passwordInfo);
    }else{
        alert("Campos incorrectos");
        console.log("Usuario: "+usuarioInfo);
        console.log("Password: "+passwordInfo);
    }
```

}

It's called by a button in a form. It used to work with the alerts and stuff... but when I tried to add the ajax part, it kept giving errors, even AFTER commenting that part, or even deleting it :/

I don't think like starting the project all over again if this keeps happening in the future, there must be some other way :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan it says this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" No idea why if it's commented out :/

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan nevermind, it got fixed, on its own :o

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan yes, but was not the problem in this case because the line was commented out and shouldn't have been read. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: I wonder if this issue has been resolved as I experienced the same issue today but the commented line is php codes within html. I don't want to ask a new question as this is already exactly the same issue that I am facing.